# URL Rewrites doesn't work when ? mark symbol in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite

I am working on Magento 2 URL Rewrites. All working well expect one. In my old website have `AccountSettings.asp?modwhat=change_b` this URL and I am trying to rewrite this, but it doesn't working for me.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected when reading Magento code. Magento rewrites are intended to be used to rewrite the request path and keep the query params (after the ? symbol) untouched.

You have two options :

- Manage this by using the rewrite rules of the webserver
- In the code by using a router

My favorite option would be to use rewrite rules.
In the end, you should not not mix Magento and webserver rewrite rules.In your case I would advice to use only webserver rewrite rules.

Comment: any examples for above rules? how to rewrite the webserver rules?

Comment: Depends what webserver you are using.
If using Apache,  it should be something like : 

```RewriteRule ^abc\/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/index.php#first [L,R=301, NE]```